# Centos7 / NetworkManager - how to reload route files?

Tags: routing, centos7, rhel7, networkmanager, nmcli

How can I reload the running NetworkManager routing configuration from the `route-XXX` files in a Centos/RHEL7 server?

I have a few servers which get routes updated directly via the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-XXX` files (part of a legacy deployment process), but when there are new routes, NetworkManager won't see the changes.

I've tried `nmcli connection reload` and `nmcli connection up ens192` without success, the running routing table is not modified.

I'm aware that the proper way would be to run a few `nmcli connection modify +ipv4.routes ...` commands, but for this particular case the reload from file is necessary.

Is there any systemd unit that should be restarted/reloaded to achieve this?